# Shipyard with existing Docker-Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm cluster (master + 2 agents). I'm installing Shipyard to have a UI.

```
cloud-user@docker-mgt:~/wordpress$ curl -sSL https://shipyard-project.com/deploy | bash -s
Deploying Shipyard
 -> Starting Database
 -> Starting Discovery
 -> Starting Cert Volume
 -> Starting Proxy
 -> Starting Swarm Manager
Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node fulfilling all dependencies: --volumes-from=shipyard-certs --link=shipyard-discovery:discovery
```

I'm running into above error. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Both [issue 615](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/issues/615) and [issue 616](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/issues/616) point to the same root cause for that error message:

> The problem is the deploy script launches an embedded Swarm container.
>   We should update it to detect an existing Swarm.
>
> If you want to bring your own Swarm manager, you will need the manual deploy: http://test.shipyard-project.com/docs/deploy/manual/

Comment: OK, so can you confirm I only need to run Datastore, Discovery, Proxy and Controller? And then in the controller link my swarm to the shipyard?

Comment: @wiwa1978 That is the idea, yes. The key point is to not detect your own swarm when deploying Shipyard.